# Pyplot interactive mode blocks Tkinter RadioButton

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to combine pyplot and Tkinter in an application. In this application, it is possible that the user first creates a figure, and afterwards opens a GUI. Now I found out that when the figure is created before opening the GUI, the Radiobutton of the GUI only returns an empty variable (in my case, an empty string), the correct value is not assigned. When there is no figure created before making the GUI, the Radiobutton works fine.

Minimal failing example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import Tkinter as tk

class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.shape = tk.StringVar()
        self.circleButton = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Circle", variable=self.shape, value='circle', command=self.selected)
        self.circleButton.pack()

    def selected(self):
        print self.shape.get()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    plt.ion()
    plt.figure()
    gui=GUI()
    gui.mainloop()
```

When running this code, clicking the Radiobutton prints an empty string, instead of 'circle'. If I remove plt.figure(), clicking the button does print 'circle' (as expected).

Can anyone tell me how I can solve this problem, and allow the user to first make a figure and then opening the GUI?

Comment: matplot may run own `mainloop` and tkinter may use only one `mainloop` to work correctly. matplot has special functions to work with Tkinter - find documentation or tutorial "how to embed plot in tkinter window"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`matplot` may use `tkinter` to create own window and to run own `mainloop`, and `tkinter` may use only one `mainloop` and one `Tk` window  to work correctly.

`tkinter` has `Toplevel` to create second/third window so you can try to use it

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import Tkinter as tk

class GUI(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.shape = tk.StringVar()
        self.circleButton = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Circle", variable=self.shape, value='circle', command=self.selected)
        self.circleButton.pack()

    def selected(self):
        print(self.shape.get())

plt.ion()
plt.figure()
GUI().mainloop()
```

---

BTW: `matplot` has special functions to work with `Tkinter` - find documentation or tutorial about `"how to embed matplotlib in Tkinter window"`